# Songs available in iTunes match is different to Mac

Tags: itunes-match

When I update iTunes match on my Mac it tells me 8,257 songs are available in iCloud. My Mac's and iOS devices all have 8,238 songs.

• A smart playlist of "matched" plus another one of "unmatched" totalled = 8,238 songs
• A smart playlist of "location=iCloud" AND "location=is not on this computer" = 0 songs
• A smart playlist of "location=iCloud" = 8,238

Any idea why the update process continually insists I have these 19 extra songs ?

Comment: Wow - almost a year later and I have exactly the same issue. For me is is just two extra songs but it is completely consistent (every computer says I have less songs that Match says are available).

Comment: I actually figured this out eventually @Frank. The difference is one or all of the following;

• icloud duplicates
• errors
• waiting                                                  • Ineligible eg pdf booklet attached to album
• music videos